# Why isn't a multiprocessing implementation of a hashing function much faster than a serial one in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, md5sum

Take the example of this code:

```
def get_hash(path, hash_type='md5'):
    func = getattr(hashlib, hash_type)()
    f = os.open(path, (os.O_RDWR | os.O_BINARY))
    for block in iter(lambda: os.read(f, 1024*func.block_size), b''):
        func.update(block)
    os.close(f)
    return func.hexdigest()
```

This function returns the md5sum of any file. Let's say I have a directory with more than 30 files and I want to run the hashing function on each file:

```
def hasher(path=some_path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, name)
            yield get_hash(path)
@some_timer_decorator
... some testing function here ...
```

**`test1 took 4.684999942779541 seconds.`**

Now, as you can see, the situation at hand gives me the opportunity to 'exploit' the `hasher` function and add multiprocessing:

```
def hasher_parallel(path=PATH):
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            full_name = os.path.join(root, name)
            yield p.apply_async(get_hash, (full_name,)).get()
@some_timer_decorator
... some other testing function here ...
```

**`test2 took 4.781000137329102 seconds.`**

The outputs are identical. I was expecting the paralleled version to be much faster, since most of the files are smaller than <20MB and the `hasher` function calculates those sums very very fast (in general, for files of that size). Is there something wrong with my implementation? If there's nothing wrong with it, is there a faster approach to the same problem?

#

This is the decorator function that I used to measure the execution time:

```
def hasher_time(f):
        def f_timer(*args, **kwargs):
            start = time.time()
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            end = time.time()
            print(f.__name__, 'took', end - start, 'seconds')
            return result
        return f_timer
```

#

Comment: BTW, why are you calling `.apply_async()` then *blocking* by calling `.get()`?

Comment: What do you mean? I thought that by using `.get()` I would actually get the result.

Comment: Yes, but `.get()` *waits for the function to complete.* You are not adding a new job to the pool until the current job has completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pushing jobs out *then wait for them to complete*:

```
yield p.apply_async(get_hash, (full_name,)).get()
```

The [`AsyncResult.get()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.get) *blocks* until the job is done, you are effectively running your jobs sequentially.

Collect the jobs, poll them with [`AsyncResult.ready()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.ready) until they are done, *then* `.get()` the results.

Better still, push all jobs into the pool with `.async_apply()` calls, then *close* the pool, call `.join()` (which blocks until all jobs are done), then retrieve results with `.get()`:

```
def hasher_parallel(path=PATH):
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    jobs = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
        for name in files:
            full_name = os.path.join(root, name)
            jobs.append(p.apply_async(get_hash, (full_name,)))
    p.close()
    p.join()  # wait for jobs to complete
    for job in jobs:
        yield job.get()
```

You could use the [`Pool.imap()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.imap) to simplify the code somewhat; it'll yield results as they come available:

```
def hasher_parallel(path=PATH):
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    filenames = (os.path.join(root, name)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False)
        for name in files)
    for result in p.imap(get_hash, filenames):
        yield result
```

but do experiment with the *chunksize* parameter and the [unordered variant](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered) as well.

Comment: The thing is, if I run the script more than once, the disk usage will remain at 0%. Only the CPU shows signs of activity.

Comment: 2 cores and 4 logical processors.

Comment: I don't see any usage example of `AsyncResult.read()`in the documentation and I don't exactly understand what you are saying. Can you give me an example?

Comment: That was exactly what I had in mind, but I didn't know how to call close() and join(). I'm still a beginner. Thank you Martijn.

Comment: That's it, you are my superhero.